# Giving multiple conditions in for loop in Java

Tags: java

I was searching for "How to give multiple conditions in a for loop?" But there are no direct answers given.

After some research I found the correct way. Conditions should not be comma(,) or semicolon(;) separated. We can use the && operator to join both the conditions together.

for( initialization ; condition1 && condition2 ; increment)

Example:

```
for(int j= 0; j < 6 && j < ((int)abc[j] & 0xff) ; j++ ) 
{
//
}
```

Hope this helps the new Java developers.

Comment: JavaBits, your post is not a question and, honestly, I'd avoid complex expressions in for loops - better keep your code simple and readable.

Comment: this was just for informtion.

Comment: You just discovered the concept of the composite boolean expression. This is not specific to for-loops.

Comment: Does any one know where to put informations in stackoverflow which can be used for future reference, it will be good for everyone .

Comment: Please keep this open, it just saved me!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can also use "or" operator,

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 || someOtherCondition() ; i++ ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 16):

A basic for statement includes

- 0..n initialization statements (`ForInit`)
- 0..1 expression statements that evaluate to `boolean` or `Boolean` (`ForStatement`) and
- 0..n update statements (`ForUpdate`)

If you need multiple *conditions* to build your ForStatement, then use the standard logic operators (`&&`, `||`, `|`, ...) *but* - I suggest to use a private method if it gets to complicated:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; isMatrixElement(i,j,myArray); i++, j++) { 
   // ...
}
```

and

```
private boolean isMatrixElement(i,j,myArray) {
  return (i < myArray.length) && (j < myArray[i].length);  //  stupid dummy code!
}
```

Comment: so embarrassing i didnt know multiple statements were allowed in initialization and update of a for loop in java. Is this one of those things that exist but should be used very sparingly? probably because of readability

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to use multiple variables and conditions in a for loop like in the example given below.

```
 for (int i = 1, j = 100; i <= 100 && j > 0; i = i - 1 , j = j-1) {
     System.out.println("Inside For Loop");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a code with a pretty look, you can do a break:

```
for(int j = 0; ; j++){
    if(j < 6
    && j < ( (int) abc[j] & 0xff)){
        break;
    }

    // Put your code here
}
```

Comment: actually I don't think this version looks prettier than the same expression within the for (...) construct.

Comment: This have a better look for complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace complicated condition with single method call to make it less evil in maintain.