# Multiple conditions on for loop

Tags: java

I am writing a for loop as follows:

```
for(int i = row, int j = col; i < rows, j < cols; i++, j++)
```

However, it appears Java isn't liking it... Is there any way I can achive something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: `or(int i = row,j = col; i < rows, j < cols; i++, j++)` you can't have multiple declarations in `for loop`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving multiple conditions in for loop in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106658/giving-multiple-conditions-in-for-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use &&. Also, `int` only once.

`for(int i = row, j = col; i < rows && j < cols; i++, j++)`

Comment: @user1876047 If you are satisfied with the answer, then it's a good practice to accept it.

Comment: Note, This will not iterate of every cell, just the diagonal from a fixed point.  I suspect this is not what you reall want.

Answer (score 1):

The second expression needs to be a boolean expresion, so

```
i < rows, j < cols
```

is not a boolean. You could try

```
i < rows && j < cols
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i = row,j = col; i < rows&& j < cols; i++, j++)` you can't have multiple declarations in `for loop` and should have single `boolean` expression