# How to use two conditions (greater than and less than) for termination of a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, operators

I was wondering, do you have a neat way of doing this ?

```
for (int i = 0; 4 > i < banners.size() ; i++) {
    doSomeThing
}
```

bannrs.size maybe between 0 to 10 but i want just 4 time or less do work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions on for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184219/multiple-conditions-on-for-loop)

Comment: yes it is look like that,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the conditions like this:

```
for (int i = 0; 4 > i && i < banners.size() ; i++) {
}
```

But this loop will terminate right away, so you probably want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < banners.size() ; i++) {
  if(4 > i){
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(4,banners.size()) ; i++) {

}
```

BTW, based on your question's title, perhaps you intended to have `i` in the range `4 < i < banners.size()`. If that's the case, you can simply initialize `i` to 5:

```
for (int i = 5; i < banners.size() ; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start your loop with 4 because all the other conditions less than 4 are not going to fulfill your requirement and waste of iteration.
So the loop goes
 for(int i=4;i

}